# Drupal 7: module to add a simple button in admin menu

Tags: drupal, module

I am trying to create a simple module that add a button in the admin/config menu. I need the button to run a php script on click. So far I've browsed dozens tutorials, but I am not able even to see the enabled module in admin/config menu as an item (even though I have used code which should just redirect to `node/1`).

Here is the code I have used:

```
function send_reminders_menu() {

$items['admin/config/reminders'] = array(
    'title' => 'Reminders Control Panel',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_goto',
    'page arguments' => array('node/1'),
    'access arguments' => array('access reminders control panel'),
    'weight' => 50,
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
  );
  return $items;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `MENU_LOCAL_TASK`  to `MENU_NORMAL_ITEM`.

`MENU_LOCAL_TASK` expects the one-level_up menu router item to be as a `MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK` but `admin/config` isn't. 
`MENU_NORMAL_ITEM` adds a normal menu item.

Lastly, don't forget to clear caches when you've made changes. 
Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, I did that, but it seems that there is another problem, for the menu item is still not visible. Interesting thing is that when I type the path at the address bar "/admin/config/reminders" - there is an error: "Access Denied. You are not authorized to access this page."

Comment: @user2056853 You have a permissions problem then - make sure you're actually defining `access reminders control panel` in `hook_permission()`, and that the user account you're trying to access the page with has that permission assigned